# Changing url with parameters in gwt framework

Tags: java, events, url, gwt

Could someone give me an example how to use celltable in case I would like to change url?

I have a simple celltable -

[image: grid]

On session select I would like to change url to something like this -

```
localhost#main?sessions=20,21
```

I have already read about `placeControllers` and etc.

But I don't find any example of using url **with parameters**.

What I have to do when **select event** is calling?

What I have to do when **place(history) event** is calling?

Answer (score 0):

Using history token in GWT is quite simple, just read little bit about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory).

Basically when you want to change history token, just build string you want and use [History.newItem(token)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#newItem%28java.lang.String%29). Not sure what do you want to do afterwards, but usually you have to register handler with [History.addValueChangeHandler()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#addValueChangeHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeHandler%29) to react to new "state"

To find out actually selected items, you need kind of [selection model](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#selection). But not sure when do you want to trigger the change..

Comment: parameters are just the way how you encode your history token, it absolutely up to you how you use it, it is just string - you build it and you have to know how to parse it.

Comment: As I understand, you offer to call History.newItem(token) when select event is calling. But let imagine that a man would like to load my url. For example url is localhost#main?sessions=20,21. I need to select this sessions. So, I will call History.newItem(token), but I don't need to call it in this situation.

Comment: when someone will load your application with any token, you have to initialize the state of the application according to it, i.e. update selection model to select 20 and 21. As you say, you don't need to call History.newItem(token) in such case, it is already set. You can use [fireCurrentHistoryState](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#fireCurrentHistoryState()) during initialization and handle history change event accordingly.